# IBoutlet won't show on main story board?

Tags: ios

Im beginner, practicing how to develop. I ran into a problem i can't solve. I created an Iboutlet for cell but it won't show up on main story board heres my code [heres my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Glgn.png)

I was trying to link iboutlet to this cell
[the cell with pokemon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGMAF.png)

Im thinking its the code from line 21 to 32

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do not post screenshots. Post the code as text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem**.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are initializing a cell with the reuse identifier of "pokecell". Make sure that you select that cell in your storyboard and set it's identifier to "pokecell".

[image]

Comment: another hint, put a print statement in your if and else statements. When you run your code you will see if the if statement succeeds or fails.